# How to find out which ArcSOM each ArcSOC belongs to?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

We have 5 ArcGIS Servers and 1 Web Server. based on the system design proposed by the company the ArcSOM will be installed on the WebServer, and the Other 5 server will host only ArcSOC. how to find out each ArcSOC to which ArcSOM belongs. I monitor all process on all machines, and I found that ArcSOM is installed on all machines, but I am not sure during how the  post installation configured and if the ArcSOC's belongs to one ArcSOM.

Comment: According to me Try to figure out ArcSOC first (Check the keycode file on every soc machine (C:\Program Files\ESRI\License10.0\sysgen folder) and ArcSOM you can install at any machines . I think you have set fail-over configuration..I am researching on this at my side..

Comment: +1 It depends upon installation type also ( like single box /Distributed installation )

Comment: It's Distributed installation (should be), and this is what I want to make sure from

Comment: Have you followed the Distributed Install help? It talks about how you install SOM component on One Machine and Soc Component on different machines and link them.

Comment: Have u got a architeture diagram of ur setup that u could include in ur Q?